# JOOQ mock result with mocked fields

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm writing UT's for a project that uses JOOQ library to query over SQL, and I need to mock the SQL response.

I've tried following [this manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/), however, we use JOOQ with pure SQL, meaning we don't have any predefined classes for Fields or Tables.

My question is - how can I define the Result object, without providing a Field as parameter? or defining a mock field param?

```
        Result<Record2<Integer, String>> result = create.newResult(AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);    // replace the AUTHOR.ID and AUTHOR.LAST_NAME with some string for example
        result.add(create.newRecord(AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME));
        result.get(0).setValue(AUTHOR.ID, 1);
        result.get(0).setValue(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, "Orwell");
        mock[0] = new MockResult(1, result);
```

I noticed that I can define a new field, but the interfaces that Field implements are quite extensive, so I'm looking for something simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you're using jOOQ without the code generator, you will want to construct `Table` and `Field` references dynamically using the plain SQL API. To quote your example:

```java
// Dynamic field creation
Field<Integer> id = field(name("AUTHOR", "ID"), SQLDataType.INTEGER);
Field<String> lastName = field(name("AUTHOR", "LAST_NAME"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR);

// Same as before
Result<Record2<Integer, String>> result = create.newResult(id, lastName);
result.add(create.newRecord(id, lastName).values(1, "Orwell"));
mock[0] = new MockResult(1, result);
```

See the following sections of the manual for details:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names